# Is it possible to test "POST" request locally? if yes, how?

Tags: mod-wsgi, werkzeug

I am building a rest api using mod-wsgi and werkzeug. I am able to test the api for get request locally. But, not able to do the same for POST request. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

check out https://www.postman.com/

or https://insomnia.rest/

you can store calls, document, make test suites, and much more